# Recommended jquery widget for time entry?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a need for a time entry widget for lengths of time but it needs to support > 24 hours entry i.e. not be constrained to a maximum of 23:59.

I want to be able to enter values up to 99:59 - i.e. 99 hours, 59 minutes.

I've seen and used jquery.timeentry.js which is excellent, but is based on a Date object which won't handle my requirements.

Are there any jquery plugins which would handle my requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a try to http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/.

See the [Set the time range](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#example8) example.

I set an example for you at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/diosney/fYEuQ/6/). You can adjust the hourMax and hourMin values to fit your requirements. For a complete reference of the timepicker options see the [link above](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

Answer (score 1):

If it's for usage on a touch device, like a smartphone or tablet, take a look at the [Mobiscroll Timespan](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/timespan/timespandhm)

It is a wheel-type scrollable control, with multiple wheels.