# What's the cleanest way to allow a user to specify a range of date / time stamps in html / javascript?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, user-controls, timestamp

I have a simple javascript which displays data on a canvas between two timestamps.

Most of the time, my users are likely to want to quickly navigate to a specific range of dates / times but sometimes thwy will also want to explicitly state a range.

Is there libraries etc. which could be used for this or should I just roll my own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recommended jquery widget for time entry?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084800/recommended-jquery-widget-for-time-entry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution with [timepicker](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon).